# Can I measure total time it take to put item in DynamoDB (Network + DynamoDB)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDB Streams only gives time when DB writes items it into. I want to find time gape between Operation Request arrival time and completion time

Does AWS Provides any service or Is there any way to find how much time does it takes to process Table operation (Insert, UpDate, Delete etc.) in DynamoDB.

Also consider Throttling in above scenario that increases time between above two things.

Constraints
   I can't change code that is performing this DB operation.

Comment: Please mention details of what all you have tried so far so those aspects can be taken into consideration by anyone helping you

Comment: I edited it. Actually its related to Continues DB monitoring using APM tools like DynaTrace or AppDynamics. I just want to monitor DB operation time at DynamoDB.